# R: Multiplying One Column to the Rest of the Data Frame Based on Index/Position

Tags: r, indexing

I have this:

```
Keyword   1    2    3    4   Pos  Bid
a        0.8  0.6  0.4  0.2   1    5
b        0.9  0.7  0.5  0.3   3    9
c        0.6  0.3  0.2  0.1   2    7
d        0.5  0.4  0.4  0.2   4    2
```

I need to multiple columns 1 through 4 by Bid except for the column indicated by Pos for each row so that I get this:

```
Keyword     1       2       3       4
a           5     5*0.6   5*0.4   5*0.2
b         9*0.9   9*0.7     9     9*0.3
c         7*0.6     7     7*0.2   7*0.1
d         2*0.5   2*0.4   2*0.4     2
```

The columns are in fact named as "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", and "10".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to work

```
colindx <- grep("\\d", names(df))
df[, colindx] <- df[, colindx] * df$Bid
df[, colindx][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Pos)] <- df$Bid
df
##   Keyword  X1  X2  X3  X4 Pos Bid
## 1       a 5.0 3.0 2.0 1.0   1   5
## 2       b 8.1 6.3 9.0 2.7   3   9
## 3       c 4.2 7.0 1.4 0.7   2   7
## 4       d 1.0 0.8 0.8 2.0   4   2
```

Some explanations:

`grep("\\d", names(df))` selects only the column names that are containing numbers in them and I multiply these column by  `df$Bid`

The second step is to the columns per each row that specified in `Pos` using `cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Pos)` and insert the actual bids into them using `<- df$Bid`

Comment: I'm just grabbing all the column names that contain numbers in them, as you said that in your real data you have columns from 1:10. So this will work on your real data too

Comment: Oh, ok.  I just didn't know what it did.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, David.  Yes, the code does work.  Now it's a matter of examining whether this result works well with the rest of my project or whether adjustments need to be made to my overall strategy.